Diameter of the complement of connected component (connected hull of open set?)
Let $U\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be an open, connected and bounded set. We know that $\mathrm{cl}\,U$ is compact and $\mathbb R^n\setminus \mathrm{cl}\, U$ has exactly one unbounded connected component $C$. Moreover, $\mathbb R^n\setminus C$ is connected and regularly closed. How can I prove that $\mathrm{diam}\,(\mathbb R^n\setminus C)=\mathrm{diam}\, U$?

What did you try and where did you get stuck?

I don't know where to start. My idea was that $\mathbb R^n\setminus C$ is contained in the convex hull of $\mathrm{cl}, U$, which has the same diameter as $U$.

You have to prove two inequalities, which one could you prove?

Obviously $\mathrm{diam}, (\mathbb R^n\setminus C) \geq \mathrm{diam}, U$, because $U\subset \mathbb R^n\setminus C$.
